# Is there any benefit of using SPM instead of Cocoapods in terms of build time?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I'd like to know if there's any significant build time savings if we use SPM instead of Cocoapods to integrate frameworks.

Comment: In my experience, no. But you should really measure for yourself, with your dependencies.

Comment: What would be the source of the benefit you're envisioning?

Comment: @RobNapier Trying to reduce the code build time, so wanted to know like if we migrate framework from Cocoapods to SPM do we find any improvement in build time ?